# removeListener vs. removeManagedListener

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Could someone please give me a compare and contrast of `removeListener` and `removeManagedListener` methods in ExtJs. When would I want to use one versus the other on a component? All i want to do is simply remove  an event listener on a component, but I am unsure of which to use.

Comment: Well, you should use `removeManagedListener` on listeners added using `addManagedListeners`...

Comment: This gives a pretty good explanation: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?172368-Managed-vs-Unmanaged-Listeners